# Access denied when importing SSAS metadata into OBIEE

Tags: ssas, business-intelligence, olap, obiee

We are currently investigating the viability of using OBIEE as the presentation tier for our BI solution (SQL Server 2012, using both the database and analysis services).  IIS (which is utilized as a pass through for OBIEE to access SSAS via XMLA) is version 7.

When trying to import SSAS cube metadata into OBIEE, we are receiving "401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials".  The connection from IIS to SSAS has been tested via Excel and established as working.  Looking at the IIS logs, it appears that the username is not passed through when connecting via OBIEE, but is passed through when using Excel.

We have also tried using a local user to no avail.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Undoubtedly there is a better solution, however, here is how I was able to get it to work.

- Use anonymous authentication on IIS
- Provide IUSR access to the cubes in question
- Configure IIS to accept connections from the OBIEE server only, for
  the XMLA pass-through site in IIS

Now, certainly less than ideal, but works.